# Improving performance of Rails model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, optimization

I have the following model that allows Users to cast Votes on Photos.

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :value

    belongs_to :photo
    belongs_to :user

    validates_associated :photo, :user
    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :photo_id
    validates_uniqueness_of :photo_id, :scope => :user_id
    validates_inclusion_of :value, :in => [-2,-1,1,2], :allow_nil => true

    after_save :write_photo_data

    def self.score
        dd = where( :value => -2 ).count
        d = where( :value => -1 ).count
        u = where( :value => 1 ).count
        uu = where( :value => 2 ).count
        self.compute_score(dd,d,u,uu)
    end

    def self.compute_score(dd, d, u, uu)
        tot = [dd,d,u,uu].sum.to_f
        score = [-5*dd, -2*d, 2*u, 5*uu].sum / [tot,4].sum*20.0
        score.round(2)
    end

    private
        def write_photo_data
            self.photo.score = self.photo.votes.score
            self.photo.save!
        end

end
```

This functions very well, however computing the score for a photo is pretty slow - it seems to take 7-12 seconds on average. I've tried adding indices for `photo_id`, `user_id`, and one combined for `photo_id` and `value`, but this hasn't really improved the performance as far as I can tell.

I'd be interested in feedback from any serious rails gurus (I'm totally an amateur) as to how this could be optimized / improved. How would you tally up votes for a particular photo and value?

Thanks!

--EDIT--

Note that the scores: `-2,-1,1,2` represent "two-thumbs down, one-thumb down, thumb up, two-thumbs up", not specific values. I could match these to the values I've assigned to them in the compute score method, but I haven't done that so far because I may want to tweak the weightings over time after seeing more data accumulated.

Also, regardless of how I represent those four possible votes in the DB, I still need both the COUNT of each kind of vote as well as the weighted value of those votes for each photo to compute the score. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an index on value, by itself.  combined indexes only work when the query has both components, starting at the left. Since your where clause does not specify a photo id, it's not using your combined index.

*update* see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is asking the database once instead of four times for the score counts:

```
Vote.where(photo_id: photo.id).group(:value).count
```

would result in a single database query and give you a hash like

```
{-2 => 21, -1 => 48, 1 => 103, 2 => 84}
```

Besides that, if you store the actual values of `[-5, -2, 2, 5]` instead of `[-2, -1, 1, 2]` in the database, you could just do

```
Vote.where(photo_id: photo.id).sum
```

and get your sum direct from the database (or even use `avg` to get the average instead)

Comment: Good idea on the group query! Do you know if that works on PostgreSQL? There are often conflicts with Postgre and Group.

Comment: I used `group` multiple times in apps on Heroku, which uses PostgreSQL. You should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you store -2, 2, 1, 2 instead of the actual grade? If you store the grade (-5 for example), you will be able to compute the score in DB directly without having to run 4 count queries. This will be an improvement for sure.

Comment: Because the -2 etc is just a representation of the four possible scores. It means "two thumbs down". What I need is a count of the "two-thumbs down" votes to calculate using the formula in the `self.compute_score` method.

Comment: "two thumbs down" is the human meaning of the "-5" grade correct? If that is the case there is no need to store -2 in the DB, you can simply store -5 and make sure that you display it properly for the user (2 thumbs down).

Comment: Ok, but even if I stored those values that way all that would change is the line `score = [-5*dd, -2*d, 2*u, 5*uu].sum / [tot,4].sum*20.0`, I still need both the count of occurrences of each value as well as the weighted value (-5 etc) of those occurances -- I don't think it's taking 12 seconds for ruby to multiply 5 by the count, I think it's taking a long time for SQL to count the occurances of each value... does that make sense?

Comment: I am not sure you are getting my point. You are looking for the score for a given photo, the score is equal to a weighted sum of 4 types of grades. If you already store the weighted grades (-5) then you simply need to sum all the grades and this can be done in the DB directly.

Comment: Remi, I do understand -- I guess the question I should be asking instead is, from my reading through logs it looks like the database is what's slowing this down, so I'm trying to find ways to shift the workload out of the database and decrease the number of queries that are run. However, if what you're saying is it would be faster to do the work in the database just construct it differently, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: Also it's the sum of the weighted grades divided by the count of unweighted grades, so I need both the sum and the count. But I do see your point about doing the sum in the DB :)

Answer (score 0):

Putting an index on the value column will speed up the SELECTs if you have lots of records in the DB.

The above posts also bring up some good points on direct optimization. However, as your DB scales, all of these approaches will eventually fall down. Since the score is a derived value, you could cache it in Memcached, Redis, or even SQL which will ensure that fetching the score scales in constant time as the app grows. You can allow the caches to get out of date and keep them updated using a background process. By doing so, your calculation function can take arbitrarily long without impacting the user experience.

Comment: Good tips! For what it's worth the score is 'cached' in the Photo model, scores are recomputed when users cast votes, which is what the `write_photo_data` callback is there for.

Comment: Oh, I see. For what it's worth, that code could be cleaned up a little. Having Vote manage Photo concerns is smelly. More importantly, if this Vote model is saved every time a vote is cast on a photo, there's no need to run the whole calculation over again on every save. Just apply a delta to Photo#score. If you add some locking, you can ensure that two votes saved at the same time don't clobber each others' updates. For belt and suspenders, fully calculate Photo#score once per day in a background job, just in case something bad happened somewhere.